# C# casting with generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I am trying to understand why casting does not work in this situation.

Assume the following interfaces:

```
public interface IDomainEvent { }

public interface IHandler<T> where T: IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T args);
}
```

And these simple implementations:

```
public class SomeEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEventHandler : IHandler<SomeEvent>
{
    public void Handle(SomeEvent args) { }
}
```

I do not understand why I cannot do this cast:

```
var handler = new SomeEventHandler() as IHandler<IDomainEvent>;
```

I am using Autofac to resolve a list of handlers based on events, which it does fine, but it creates them of course fully concrete, which at runtime I need to handle them via interfaces.  I can use reflection easy enough to call the handle method, but it seems like this should work :/

Comment: Try marking T as `out` in the interface decleration. This looks like a covariance issue.

Comment: Yeah try googling `covariance` and `contravariance`.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Then the interface definition won't compile.  It's an inherently contravariant API.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Shouldn't it be `in`?

Comment: @TimothyShields Yes, the interface is conceptually contravariant, not covariant, but then he's trying to use it in a covariant manor, so that usage sill won't work, even with that change.

Comment: @Servy Good point, missed that the interface wont work with covariance. As is, this is impossible then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't conceptually treat an `IHandler<SomeEvent>` as if it's an `IHandler<IDomainEvent>`.  An `IHandler<IDomainEvent>` needs to be able to accept an instance of `AThirdEvent` (that implements `IDomainEvent`) as a parameter to `Handle`, but your `SomeEventHandler` type can't accept `AThirdEvent` instances, only `SomeEvent` instances.

The compiler is correctly informing you that, from a conceptual perspective, this type conversion is not valid.

Conceptually your interface is actually *contravariant*.  If you had an `IHandler<IDomainEvent>` you could implicitly convert it to an `IHandler<SomeEvent>` (if you adjusted the definition of the interface to inform the compiler that it is in fact contravariant) because if your `Handle` method can accept any type of `IDomainEvent` then clearly it can accept every single `SomeEvent`.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone for your help.  That first paragraph though actually made it click in my head.

Answer (score 1):

This requires your [interface to be covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

```
public interface IHandler<out T> : where T : IDomainEvent
```

However, your interface itself wouldn't support this, as it's effectively contravariant.  Allowing this to work would not be type safe, and there is no direct workaround.  Covariant interfaces are only allowed to return `T`, not accept `T` as a parameter to a method.

For details, see [variance in generic interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx).

Comment: But the interface *isn't* covariant in its API, it's contravariant.

Comment: I did try that, but I then had this error:
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'Testing.IHandler<T>.Handle(T)'. 'T' is covariant.

Comment: @RyanLM Yes, because your interface is conceptually not covariant, so this *shouldn't* be valid, it's not the compiler telling you your otherwise valid program is invalid.

Comment: @RyanLM I updated to provide detials - hadn't looked at what you were trying to do in detail when I wrote it.  Basically, you can't do that :p

Comment: @Servy Updated to include that - was being lazy - thanks for pointing it out.